# Third party module/library issues while making apk using buildozer & Kivy

Tags: android, python, kivy, buildozer

I have posted this a lot time,but still I have not any right solution.I have a module libnmap . I installed it via `pip install python-libnmap` ,

when i write a python script which has this module imported and run it...it ran smoothly without any error in my computer....now this is pypi module so I wanted to import it to my `main.py` so in buildozer.spec in requirements `requirements = kivy,openssl,python,android,pyjnius,python-libnmap` did...then after when I write this command in terminal `buildozer android debug deploy run logcat`

It is giving me errors  like below :

```html
 I/libSDL  (23145): SDL_SetVideoMode(): application requested mode 480x744
    I/python  (23145): [INFO              ] [GL          ] OpenGL version <OpenGL ES 3.0 V@66.0 AU@04.04.04.048.076 (CL@)>
    I/python  (23145): [INFO              ] [GL          ] OpenGL vendor <Qualcomm>
    I/python  (23145): [INFO              ] [GL          ] OpenGL renderer <Adreno (TM) 305>
    I/python  (23145): [INFO              ] [GL          ] OpenGL parsed version: 3, 0
    I/python  (23145): [INFO              ] [GL          ] Texture max size <4096>
    I/MultiDex(23400): VM with version 1.6.0 does not have multidex support
    I/MultiDex(23400): install
    I/python  (23145): [INFO              ] [GL          ] Texture max units <16>
    I/MultiDex(23400): MultiDexExtractor.load(/data/app/com.google.android.gms-1.apk, false)
    I/MultiDex(23400): loading existing secondary dex files
    I/MultiDex(23400): load found 3 secondary dex files
    I/MultiDex(23400): install done
    I/python  (23145): [INFO              ] [Support     ] Android install hooks
    I/python  (23145): [INFO              ] [Window      ] virtual keyboard not allowed, single mode, not docked
    I/python  (23145): [INFO              ] [Text        ] Provider: pygame
    I/ActivityManager( 1001): Resuming delayed broadcast
    I/Process (23264): Sending signal. PID: 23264 SIG: 3
    I/dalvikvm(23264): threadid=3: reacting to signal 3
    I/ProviderInstaller(23400): Insert disabled by gate 'gms:security:enable_conscrypt_in_gms_application'
    I/ActivityManager( 1001): Start proc com.google.android.apps.magazines for broadcast com.google.android.apps.magazines/com.google.apps.dots.android.app.receiver.FirstInstallNotificationReceiver: pid=23417 uid=10119 gids={50119, 3003, 1028, 1015}
    I/python  (23145):  Traceback (most recent call last):
    I/python  (23145):    File "/root/.buildozer/android/app/main.py", line 41, in <module>
    I/python  (23145):  ImportError: No module named processing
    I/python  (23145): Python for android ended.
    I/AndroidRuntime(23145): VM exiting with result code 0, cleanup skipped.
    I/WindowState( 1001): WIN DEATH: Window{422d0570 u0 emailbomber.technhack.i
```

Please someone solve this,else give me whole method of doing this thing...

Comment: It looks like you're trying to import processing, but this module doesn't exist. Is this module part of python-libnmap?

Comment: When i run this in pc ... It works fine....but after making apk of it....it gives me this error

Comment: Yes, you probably have processing installed on the pc.

Comment: So how can i solve this???

Comment: Work out where the processing module is supposed to come from, and include it in the apk. If it's supposed to be in python-libnmap, something is wrong. If it's the processing module from pip, you're simply missing it.

Comment: I'm not sure what's the nature of its processing though - I don't know what kinds of processing are possible on android.

Comment: Hmmm... So is there any solution for this ????